# CAPTCHA connection issue obstructs legitimate questions from being posted

Tags: bug, captcha

CAPTCHA seems to be broken, which makes asking questions a hassle.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue over here?

[image: CAPTCHA connection issue]

Comment: Is the problem, perhaps, that you're located in China and reCAPTCHA is being blocked there? It is, after all, a Google service.

Comment: I'm located in Taipei. Never had this issue on SE before.

Comment: Does reCAPTCHA work on other sites? Does it work if you go to it directly? I haven't ever encountered this problem, and I get presented with anti-robot verification pretty frequently on Stack Overflow. Apparently I can click buttons as fast as a machine sometimes.

Comment: Funny thing is, the reCAPTCHA verification was omitted when I removed one of my tags.